# Modifying font of header of pivot item without modify font of its content WP8

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-8, fonts

i want to modify the font of header of pivot item without affecting the font of its content , i tried creating a custom style , and linking it to the pivot control using HeaderTemplate property , but still i am not able to get it work . Can Anyone help>

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate">
        <ContentPresenter>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        </ContentPresenter>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

    <!--Pivot Control-->
    <phone:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}">
       <phone:PivotItem Header="about">
            <!--Double line list no text wrapping-->

        </phone:PivotItem>
    </phone:Pivot>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<phone:Pivot>

    <phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                       Style="{StaticResource HeadTitleStyle}"
                       Margin="0,12" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>

</phone:Pivot>
```

**TextBlock** Style:

```
<Style x:Key="HeadTitleStyle"
       TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily"
            Value="" />
    <Setter Property="Margin"
            Value="" />
</Style>
```

Comment: My method also worked after a clean build ,then i tried yours it also worked and yours involves less code, so i will go with yours . however can you explain  what does text="{Binding}" mean ?

Comment: @varunsinghal65 It makes binding with the Header values that you have specified in the Pivot items.